# How to set files and folders to their default permissions?

Tags: debian, permissions, rsync, backup

I am using Debian and want to reinstall a backup of personal and configuration files (the entire /home folder of a user) on a new computer.

For some reason I cannot understand, every files of my entire backup has the same permissions : 777 / -rwxrwxrwx. This is way too permissive for some configuration files. For example, the first time I used ssh after reinstalling the backup, I had to do a "chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config" to be able to start ssh.

I really do not know why this happened. I backup with `rsync -av` with should preserve permissions and my external hard drive is using a ext4 filesystem.

Anyway, I have only this backup and no possibility to make another one (the computer died). I am looking for a way to set files and folder to their default settings (for example I guess .ssh/config file is 600) automatically.

Is there a way to achieve this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go;

```
ORIG_DIR="/bla/bla"
BKUP_DIR="/bla/dee"
:~$ find $ORIG_DIR | while read aline; do perm=$(stat "$aline" | grep "Access: (" | sed 's/Access: (//;s/\/.*//'); chmod -v $perm "$BKUP_DIR/$aline"; done
```

I made an example;

```
:~$ mkdir ooh
:~$ mkdir noo
:~$ touch ooh/mog1 ooh/mog2 ooh/mog3
:~$ rsync -av ooh noo
sending incremental file list
ooh/
ooh/mog1
ooh/mog2
ooh/mog3

sent 245 bytes  received 77 bytes  644.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
:~$ ls -la noo/ooh/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 mike mike 4096 Oct 28 23:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 mike mike 4096 Oct 28 23:10 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike mike    0 Oct 28 23:09 mog1
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike mike    0 Oct 28 23:09 mog2
-rw-r--r-- 1 mike mike    0 Oct 28 23:09 mog3
:~$ chmod 700 ooh/mog1
:~$ chmod 600 ooh/mog2
:~$ chmod 555 ooh/mog3
:~$ find ooh
ooh
ooh/mog1
ooh/mog3
ooh/mog2
:~$ find ooh | while read aline; do perm=$(stat "$aline" | grep "Access: (" | sed 's/Access: (//;s/\/.*//'); chmod -v $perm "noo/$aline"; done
mode of 'noo/ooh' retained as 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)
mode of 'noo/ooh/mog1' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0700 (rwx------)
mode of 'noo/ooh/mog3' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0555 (r-xr-xr-x)
mode of 'noo/ooh/mog2' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0600 (rw-------)
```